# Unable to convert pathvariable to object

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I want to have an object as a path variable but I get the below exception when testing. How can I fix this

```java
@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test/api")
public class MyRestController {

    @GetMapping("/data/{id}")
    public Data getData(@PathVariable @Valid IdData id) {
        return new Data();
    }
}
```

```java
@Data
public class IdData {

    private Integer id;

    public IdData(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Exception:

> org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException:
> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
> 'com.test.IdData'; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
> 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.test.IdData': no matching
> editors or conversion strategy found

Comment: The error tells you exactly what is wrong. In short how should Spring know how to convert a `String` to your `IdData` object? You need to write a converter for that.

Comment: Why are you using `@Valid` but then have no validation whatsoever in `IdData`?

Answer (score 0):

From "/data/{id}" you will get an id which is an integer but the method parameter is trying to get IdData value which is incompatible.

```
@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test/api")
public class MyRestController {

    @GetMapping("/data/{id}")
    public Data getData(@Valid @PathVariable int id) {
        return new Data();
    }
}
```

Output:-

```
{
   "repository": {
      "metricName": "spring.data.repository.invocations",
      "autotime": {
         "enabled": true,
         "percentilesHistogram": false,
         "percentiles": null
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could change your `@PathVariable` Data Type from `IdData` to an Integer. Just add some logic to get the `IdData` by the id in path, which can be done by using JPA's `findById()` method. It might also be easier to pass in an integer in the path rather than an entire object.